# R: Deleted Nodes are Still Showing Up After They Were Deleted

Tags: r, graph, nodes, edges

I wrote some R code that simulates some graph network based data, creates a graph, removes nodes if there are less than 2 connections and makes it an interactive graph. However, when I plot the graph, I can clearly see that nodes with 0 connections are still there (if nodes with less 2 connections are deleted, this means nodes with 1 connection and 0 connections should also be deleted).

Here is a picture that shows nodes with 0 connections have not been deleted:

[image]

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
set.seed(1234)
library(dplyr)
library(visNetwork)
library(igraph)

#create file from which to sample from
x5 <- sample(1:10000, 10000, replace=T)
#convert to data frame
x5 = as.data.frame(x5)

#create first file (take a random sample from the created file)
a = sample_n(x5, 9000)
#create second file (take a random sample from the created file)
b = sample_n(x5, 9000)

#combine
c = cbind(a,b)
#create dataframe
c = data.frame(c)
#rename column names
colnames(c) <- c("a","b")

#create graph
graph <- graph.data.frame(c, directed=F)
graph <- simplify(graph)
G=graph


#delete node if less than 1 connection

Isolated = which(degree(G)<2)
G2 = delete.vertices(G, Isolated)



#prepare for visnetwork
nodes <- data.frame(id = V(G2)$name, title = V(G2)$name)
nodes <- nodes[order(nodes$id, decreasing = F),]
edges <- get.data.frame(G2, what="edges")[1:2]

visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>%   visIgraphLayout(layout = "layout_with_fr") %>%
    visOptions(highlightNearest = TRUE, nodesIdSelection = TRUE) %>% 
    visInteraction(navigationButtons = TRUE)
```

Thanks

edit : function kindly provided by user20650

```
dirty <- function(g, n=2){  
    d = degree(g) < n 
    ds = sum(d)  
    print(ds)  
    if(ds == 0) {     
        return(g)   
    } else {    
        dirty(delete_vertices(g, which(d))) 
    } }
```

Comment: I will try to find out if there is a "keep.verticies" function (just like delete.verticies https://igraph.org/r/doc/subgraph.html)

Comment: re my thought on the degree changing `Gd3 = which(degree(G) == 3); 
G2d1 = which(degree(G2)== 1) ; intersect(Gd3, G2d1)` -- you can see that there are nodes which were degree 3 that now are degree 1 after removal

Comment: Im not familiar with igraph -- perhaps there is a function -- but I suppose you could do a recursive search; probably take ages and in the extreme case could get an empty graph returned

Comment: Try `dirty <- function(g, n=2){
  d = degree(g) < n
  ds = sum(d)
  print(ds)
  if(ds == 0) {
    return(g)
  } else {
    dirty(delete_vertices(g, which(d)))
  }
}` (spaces between code words imply newlines)

Comment: The function does a recursive search. It keeps removing the nodes with degree less than n. when there are no nodes left with degree < n it stops. It will return a graph where all the nodes have degree >= n. Try with `xx = dirty(G); table(degree(xx))`

Comment: dirty <- function(g, n=3){ d = degree(g) < n ds = sum(d) print(ds) if(ds == 0) { return(g) } else { dirty(delete_vertices(g, which(d))) } }   ... now, xx = dirty(G) aill return a graph where all nodes have more than 3 connections?

Comment: it will return nodes with degree `>=3` as a strict inequality was used in the function. If you only want nodes with > 3 then set `n=4` in the function argument or change the function to `degree(g) <= n` and use `n=3` in the function argument. Do be aware that this method could remove nodes with a lot of edges but they just happen to only connect with nodes with few edges -- such nodes may be interesting.

Comment: its so interesting - i am experimenting with the code you kindly provided, and a large (randomly generated) graph of 10,000 nodes gets reduced to a handful of nodes after the recursive partitioning